# Modify pixel color out of a box from image in R

Tags: r, image, image-processing, raster

I would like to change in black the white pixels out of a box. The box will be smaller of 50 pixels from the edges. How to do ? Or can I only select white pixel in this box ?

```
library(EBImage)
library(ggplot2)
image <- readImage('C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Cluster/Test.png')
display(image , method = "raster")

tolerance <- 50
xi <- 0 + tolerance
xf <- dim(dots)[1] - tolerance
yi <- 0 + tolerance
yf <- dim(dots)[2] - tolerance
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Laurent. I don't think your question is clear here. Could you try to explain a bit more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hello. I would like to select the white pixel located at a distance max of 50 pixels from all the border of the picture. Then I could change the  color of the selected pixel into black. My idea is to create a selection box by providing the 4 corners (xi, xf, yi and yf).